# Constructor cannot call itself c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, constructor

Constructor "Delay.vkMessages.vkMessages(string, System.DateTime, string, bool, string)" cannot call itself.I have another class, copy of this class, but it works(I can add code).How I can resolve this error?

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using ImageCacher;

    namespace Delay
    {
    public class vkMessages : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Kto { get; private set; }
        public DateTime Date_Time { get; private set; }
        public string InOrOut { get; private set; }
        public string TexT { get; private set; }
        public bool Read_State { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<vkMessages> Messages
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == _vk_messages)
                {
                    _vk_messages = MessageService.GetMessages(InOrOut, () => MessagesLoaded = true);
                }
                return _vk_messages;
            }
        }
        private IEnumerable<vkMessages> _vk_messages;
        public bool MessagesLoaded
        {
            get { return _messagesLoaded; }
            set
            {
                _messagesLoaded = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("MessagesLoaded");
            }
        }
        private bool _messagesLoaded;

        public vkMessages(string kto, DateTime date_time, string text, bool read_state)
        {
            Kto = kto;
            Date_Time = date_time;
            TexT = text;
            Read_State = read_state; 
        }
        public vkMessages(string kto, DateTime date_time,
            string text, bool read_state,string in_or_out)

            : this(kto,date_time,text,read_state,in_or_out)
        {
            InOrOut = in_or_out;

        }....
```

Comment: You are calling the wrong constructor. Call the first one. `: this(kto,date_time,text,read_state)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the last parameter:

```
public vkMessages(string kto, DateTime date_time,
                  string text, bool read_state,string in_or_out)
    : this(kto, date_time, text, read_state)
{
    InOrOut = in_or_out;
}
```

That said, your logic is skewed, it should be the other way round (i.e. this constructor should do all the work and the other constructor should call this one:

```
public vkMessages(string kto, DateTime date_time, string text, bool read_state)
    : this(kto, date_time, text, read_state, false) { }

public vkMessages(string kto, DateTime date_time,
                  string text, bool read_state,string in_or_out)
{
    InOrOut = in_or_out;
    Kto = kto;
    Date_Time = date_time;
    TexT = text;
    Read_State = read_state; 
}
```

Finally, you should fix your identifiers to conform to the .NET guidelines. In particular, a class should follow the PascalCase convention of starting with an upper-case letter.

Comment: +1: I would also like to add that cross-calling constructors is leading to lots of mistakes (double-initialising etc) where I am currently contracting. I personally would avoid overusing that "feature" of C# just to save a few lines of code. USE WITH CAUTION.