# Constructor cannot call itself (calling private constructor with base class argument)

Tags: c#

This is similar to the question asked here: [Constructor cannot call itself c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563798/constructor-cannot-call-itself-c-sharp) In fact some people probably will point out that it is the same, but I can't figure out what needs to be done because of the differences in implementation.

While compiling the code below, I am getting the error:

> Constructor "..." cannot call itself

```
public class ImprovementWithProductionCost : IComparable
{
    public ImprovementWithProductionCost(StarSystemImprovement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider)
        : this(improvement, costResolutionContext, costProvider)
    {
        this.ImprovementDefinitionName = improvement.StarSystemImprovementDefinition.Name;
    }

    public ImprovementWithProductionCost(PlanetImprovement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider)
        : this(improvement, costResolutionContext, costProvider)
    {
        this.ImprovementDefinitionName = improvement.PlanetImprovementDefinition.Name;
    }

    private ImprovementWithProductionCost(Improvement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider)
    {
        this.Improvement = improvement;
        for (int i = 0; i < costProvider.Costs.Length; i++)....
```

So, unlike of how it is in the similar question, I do need to call private constructor with the same amount of arguments as the public one. And the public one constains different class types for the improvement argument.

I seem to be lacking a bit of knowledge of how to refactor this properly.

Based on the comments, here is the representation of the Imrovement class hyrarchy. It is good to have I suppose for the class refactoring suggestions, but as for the answer to the original question casting (as in accepted answer) fixes it.

```
public abstract class Improvement : SimulationObjectWrapper, IGameEntity, IDescriptorEffectProvider, IEncounterEntityProvider, IEncounterGlobalEffectProvider
{
    protected Improvement(GameEntityGUID guid, string name) : base(string.Format("{0}#{1}", name, guid))
    {
        this.GUID = guid;
    }

    protected Improvement()
    {
    } 

public class PlanetImprovement : Improvement
{
    public PlanetImprovement(GameEntityGUID guid, PlanetImprovementDefinition planetImprovementDefinition) : base(guid, "PlanetImprovement")
    {
        base.GUID = guid;
        this.PlanetImprovementDefinition = planetImprovementDefinition;
    }

    protected PlanetImprovement()
    {
    }
```

***Note1:*** StarSystemImprovement is very similar to PlanetImprovement, so I suppose there is no need to explicetely show it.

***Note2:*** Please note, that is is a little bit tricky to show just the necessary part of each class / subclass. So, appologies if I have missed something

Comment: Assuming inheritance is at play: `this((Improvement)improvement, ...`

Comment: You can do this by explicitly casting the arguments to the specific type: `this((Improvement) improvement, costResolutionContext, costProvider)`. However, this arrangement is definitely dubious in that it's not clear why there's an inheritance hierarchy involved where `ImprovementWithProductionCost` can't just take any `Improvement`, as this suggests your type relationships are a bit wonky, or your base `Improvement` is lacking a `virtual` member for getting the `Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the *number* of arguments per se, it's the fact that you're literally telling the compiler to have the constructor for `(StarSystemImprovement, ICostResolutionContext, ICostProvider)` call the constructor for `(StarSystemImprovement, ICostResolutionContext, ICostProvider)` — the exact same constructor.

I assume `StarSystemImprovement` and `PlanetImprovement` each inherit from `Improvement`. To make the call go to the private constructor expecting an `Improvement`, cast it so that the type is just `Improvement`, not a subtype:

```
public class ImprovementWithProductionCost : IComparable
{
    public ImprovementWithProductionCost(StarSystemImprovement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider) : this((Improvement)improvement, costResolutionContext, costProvider)
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        this.ImprovementDefinitionName = improvement.StarSystemImprovementDefinition.Name;
    }

    public ImprovementWithProductionCost(PlanetImprovement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider) : this((Improvement)improvement, costResolutionContext, costProvider)
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        this.ImprovementDefinitionName = improvement.PlanetImprovementDefinition.Name;
    }

    private ImprovementWithProductionCost(Improvement improvement, ICostResolutionContext costResolutionContext, ICostProvider costProvider)
    {
        this.Improvement = improvement;
        for (int i = 0; i < costProvider.Costs.Length; i++)....
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal, reproducible example:

```
public class BaseArg { }

public class DerivedArg : BaseArg { }

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(BaseArg baseArg) { }
    public Foo(DerivedArg derivedArg) : this(derivedArg) { }
}
```

You're telling the `Foo(DerivedArg derivedArg)` constructor to call itself by `this(derivedArg)` (`derivedArg` is of the type `DerivedArg`, which matches one constructor, namely itself).

The solution is to cast the argument to the base type, causing the compiler to call `Foo(BaseArg baseArg)` instead:

```
: this((BaseArg)derivedArg)
```